# Regex: combine 2 rules into 1

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i have an `.htacces` rule. I need to find the first integer after a dot (or not). Here's a good sample of good data that matches and finds the first capturing group:

```
discography/type
discography/type/
discography/type/4
discography/type/albums.4
```

here's a bad sample of data:

```
discography/type/4//
discography/type//
discography/type/singles.4//
```

The rule that works:

```
RewriteRule ^discography\/type(?:\/(?:(?:[^\/]*[.])?(\d+)\/?|[^\/]+\/?)?)?$ discography/releases.php?type=$1 [L,QSA]
```

So far, it's all good: https://regex101.com/r/4BwJ7z/1

Here's where i need help.

I also have another rule that matches a few keywords (`ep`, `singles`) as the first capturing group:

```
discography/ep
discography/ep/
discography/singles
discography/singles/

RewriteRule ^discography\/(ep|singles)\/?$ discography/releases.php?type=$1 [L,QSA]
```

https://regex101.com/r/dGEDdx/1

I need to combine these 2 rules into 1.
Any ideas?

Comment: It can be done using alterations, something like this: [`^discography\/(?:(ep|singles)\/?$|type(?:\/(?:(?:[^\/]*[.])?(\d+)\/?|[^\/]+\/?)?)?$) discography/releases.php?type=$1$2`](https://regex101.com/r/BeYDZW/1). But I doubt that it is in any way better than using two rewrite rules.

Comment: Your solution contains 2 capturing groups. I'm looking for 1 capturing group so i can `$_GET` the value in php without double verification. Is it possible using 1 capturing group?

Comment: Have you looked into link I provided? As a result, only one of groups will be substituted.

Comment: What should be the target rewrite for `discography/type/` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***1st solution:*** In a Single rule, combination of both the Rules please try following .htaccess rules. Here is the [Online demo of regex](https://regex101.com/r/6vN37i/1).

```
RewritEngine ON

RewriteRule ^discography\/(?:(ep|singles)|type(?:\/?(?:(?:[^\/]*[.])?(\d+)\/?|[^\/]+\/?)?))\/?$ discography/releases.php?type=$1$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

---

***2nd solution:*** How about keeping both the Rules into your .htaccess rules file. I mean at a time only rule could be passed right? So $1 should give 1 value only. I also added `NC` flag to it to enable ignore case on the rules.

```
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteRule ^discography\/(ep|singles)\/?$ discography/releases.php?type=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^discography\/type(?:\/(?:(?:[^\/]*[.])?(\d+)\/?|[^\/]+\/?)?)?$ discography/releases.php?type=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```